# List is taking too much time

Tags: c#, list

I have been writing a program which has a list of 100,000 elements I have to process all the elements with different conditions. This does not take much time 3sec at most. After this I have a list of valid entries and my orignal list which had 100000 elements. The new list usualy has a size of 6K - 7K. The main problem is when I use List.Remove function or any other way to  remove the invalid elements from the orignal list with 100K elements its too slow.

Please guide if I should use any thing else then the LIST or there is something that I can do with this code also.

I am including all codes I tried.

```
for( int k = 0; k < initialList.Count;k++)
{
    combo c = initialList.ElementAt(k);
    if(invalidEntries.Contains(c))
    {
        smartString.Append(c.number1.ToString());
        smartString.Append(c.number2.ToString());
        smartString.Append(c.number3.ToString());
        smartString.Append(c.number4.ToString());
        smartString.Append(c.number5.ToString());
        smartString.Append("   Sum : ");
        smartString.Append(c.sum.ToString());
        smartString.AppendLine();
        InvalidCombo.AppendText(smartString.ToString());
        smartString.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        smartString.Append(c.number1.ToString());
        smartString.Append(c.number2.ToString());
        smartString.Append(c.number3.ToString());
        smartString.Append(c.number4.ToString());
        smartString.Append(c.number5.ToString());
        smartString.Append("   Sum : ");
        smartString.Append(c.sum.ToString());
        smartString.AppendLine();

        validCombo.AppendText(smartString.ToString());
        smartString.Clear();
    }
}
```

Also

```
for(int k=0;k<100000;k++)
{
    combo c = initialList.ElementAt(k);
    if (!invalidEntries.Contains(c))
        validEntries.Add(c);
}
```

I have also tried the .remove functions but i think list cant take it. so any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Is this a U/I component or a collection?  Maybe you need to re-think your design if you are trying to show 100K items in a U/I component?

Comment: Try using a StringDictionary instead of a list and have your program provide the key of the dictionary entry when removing items from the dictionary.  The dictionary is much easier to search than the list.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes its a UI Program but the list is generated in code. It is a list of structure and the structure has 6 integer elements. the time is not taken in showing in ui but in processing part which is given above

Comment: @JeffPrince Thanks let me check that as well.

Comment: @JeffPrince well I have a structure of ints x 6 which I have to process. and it seems the StringDictionary is for strings

Comment: Sorry, I got that backwards.  Why don't you try using HashSet<int> and see if that gets you better performance.  It has most/all of the methods you are probably using with List, such as Add, Remove, etc.  I can provide a sample if you need it.

Comment: I don't see any remove like code in your examples. What really do you need - removing all the items from the `initialList` that are not contained in the `invalidEntries`? Then what is `validEntries`  in your second try? Also what is the type of all these lists - List<combo>? Also is `combo` class or struct?

Comment: combo is a struct.
      public struct combo
        {
            public int number1;
            public int number2;
            public int number3;
            public int number4;
            public int number5;
            public int sum;
            public bool invalid;
        }
Well I want to remove the invalid from initial to get the valid entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of the `struct`s, but you must be very careful when you work with a `struct` like yours. The `List<T>` methods that rely on equality (`Contains`, `IndexOf`, `Remove`) may not work and should not be used. Same for `HashSet<T>` and similar.
The best for your case would be to combine the processing with the removal. And the fastest way to do a removal from a `List<T>` is to **not use** it's item remove related (`Remove`/`RemoveAt`) methods! :-) Instead, you "compact" the list by keeping the items that should remain (and their count) at the beginning of the list, and then just use `RemoveRange` method to cut the unnecessary items at the end of the list. This is very efficient and avoids all the data block moving which happens when you use the "normal" list remove methods. Here is a sample code based on your struct definition:

```
public struct combo { public int number1; public int number2; public int number3; public int number4; public int number5; public int sum; public bool invalid; }

void ProcessList(List<combo> list)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = list[i];
        ProcessItem(ref item);
        if (!item.invalid) list[count++] = item;
    }
    list.RemoveRange(count, list.Count - count);
}

void ProcessItem(ref combo item)
{
    // do the processing and set item.invalid=true/false
}
```

In case you are not mutating the item inside the `ProcessItem`, you can remove the `ref` modifier, change the return type to `bool` and use it to control whether the item should be removed from the list or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using HashSet.  It is very fast.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myInts = new HashSet<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
                myInts.Add(i);

            myInts.Remove(62345);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I think I misread your code a little and it is not the ints you're having trouble with but instead whatever structure you're using.  The answer though is still the same, use HashSet<T> and for T specify whatever the structure is.